# Can't subtract two hours in php

Tags: php, date, subtraction

Im trying to subtract tow hours, this is my code (`crono()` subtracts two hours):

```
include("classes/Functions.php");//contains crono()
include("classes/database.php");//database connection

$selectActual = "SELECT * from InfActual WHERE state='on'";
$resultActual = $conn->query($selectActual);
if ($resultActual->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($rowActual = $resultActual->fetch_assoc()) {
        $horaIni = $rowActual['horaIni'];
        $actual = date("h:i:s");
        echo "horaini: ".$horaIni." actual: ".$actual."<br>";
        echo "subtract: ".crono($hora, $actual)."<br>";
    }
}
```

And this is the result

```
horaini: 05:41:25 actual: 05:53:43
subtract: 05:53:43
```

I think the problem is that `$rowActual['horaIni']` is not in the same format as `$actual` (I'm not totally sure), I don't know how to solve this.

**[Solved]**

```
echo "subtract: ".crono($horaIni, $actual)."<br>";
```

Comment: Output the values for $rowActual['horaIni'] and $actual. Additionally, seeing crono() function would be helpful.

Comment: Without the code to `crono()` we can't really help you

Comment: Why are you using `$hora` in the crono function and not `$horaIni`?

Comment: where does the variable $hora come from? not a lot to go on here.

Comment: you need to post your `crono` function to get an answer. time manipulation is tricky. you may consider doing in your query using mysql date manipulation functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm so stupid, I'm not using $horaIni in crono function. So sorry.

Comment: @Safira Just a suggestion: Add this as an answer and select it since you solved it.  That way people searching for your question will see that there is indeed a selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm so stupid, I'm not using `$horaIni` in `crono()` function. So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in sql?

```
SELECT *, horaini - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AS horaini2
```

In php you would use strtotime()

```
date('H:i:s', strtotime($rowActual['horaIni']) - 60 * 60 * 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime`

```
echo date("h:i:s", strtotime($actual."-2 hour"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$oldDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');
$newDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa', strtotime('-2 hours'));

echo $oldDate;
echo "<BR>";
echo $newDate;

?>
```

This should do the trick